# Преобразование и использование координат GPS

Tags: gps

В будущем приложении планирую получать координаты gps, однако работать с градусами невозможно. Один градус по широте не равен одному градусу по долготе в переводе на метры да еще и соотношение м/градусы по широте уменьшается с отдалением от экватора. Я хочу преобразовать полученные данные в систему координат в метрах, которая гарантирует соблюдение пропорций в любой точке на поверхности Земли и соответственно преобразовывать эти координаты обратно в градусы.
К примеру я хочу взять выбранную точку на карте, преобразовать ее в искомую систему координат, добавить +1 км по x и +1 км по y, преобразовать результат обратно углы и отобразить на карте. При этом чтобы Google Maps показывало расстояние между выбранной и найденой точками равное sqrt(2) не зависимо от положения начальной точки.
  Посоветуйте, существует ли такая система координат или как мне лучше решить мою задачу.
  Наткнулся на UTM, однако меня запутали зоны. Не понимаю как выполнять операции над такой системой координат.

Comment: Вам нужно хотя бы немножко, на начальном уровне, ознакомиться с той предметной областью, для которой вы планируете писать свое приложение. Вы пишете: "Я хочу преобразовать полученные данные в систему координат в метрах, которая гарантирует соблюдение пропорций в любой точке на поверхности Земли". Это невозможно в принципе. Поверхность земли - не плоскость, а сфера (точнее - геоид). Нельзя расстелить апельсиновую кожуру по столу так, чтобы она не порвалась и пропорции на ней не исказились. Почитайте про картографические проекции, потом поищите библиотеки для работы с ними.

Comment: Начните хотя бы с этого: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F, http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/RU:GIS_for_Dummies_(written_by_a_dummy)